# If the spinner is spun 2 times what is the probability that it lands on "A" both times

Tags: probability

If the spinner is spun 2 times what is the probability that it lands on "A" both times.
[image]

My answer is **3/16** and here is how I got it:

> I divided the whole circle into 8 equal parts out of which 3 parts
>   are of A. so the probability of landing on A would be 3/8 on first
>   spun. Therefore, for spinning the spinner twice then the probability
>   of landing it on A would be (3/8)/2=3/16

But answer key is showing **1/64** which is not matching with my answer and therefore I would like to ask experts here.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: What is the probability it lands on A the first time? The second time?

Comment: My answer is 3/16 but the answer key showing 1/64. Can someone explain?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your working and explain how you did it.

Comment: @IanMiller I divided 3/8 by 2 for spinning the spinner two times

Comment: I don't know where the 1/64 could come from.  Maybe there's a typo.  Perhaps the regions were intended to be labeled (starting with the "A" at one-o-clock and going clockwise) A, B, C, D.  In that case, the probability of hitting A once would be 45/360 = 1/8, and the probability of hitting A twice would be (1/8)*(1/8) = 1/64.  How did you come up with 3/16???

Comment: @Addy You don't want to divide by two to get the same event twice. Rather, you raise the probability by the power of two. If you wanted to know the probability of getting A three times in a row, you raise it by the power of three.

Comment: @MatthewBusche I divided the whole circle into 8 equal parts out of which 3 parts are of A. so the probability of landing on A would be 3/8 on first spun. Therefore, for spinning the spinner twice then the probability of landing it on A would be (3/8)/2=3/16

Comment: Thanks all for clarifying my doubts. I am a sixth grader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chance of anding on A for one spin is $\frac{90+45}{360}=\frac{3}{8}$. So the probability of that happening twice in a row is $\frac{3}{8}\times\frac{3}{8}=\frac{9}{64}$.

Comment: Answer key says 1/64.

Comment: @Addy Answer key is wrong. Ian Miller is right.